# Vue with Webpack: Options should NOT have additional properties

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack

While I was trying to update npm packages, this error popped up which doesn't give any details. I tried to check if is because of my webpack config, but is not because I tried running webpack without using my config.

I saw on other forums this error but it was thrown one or two times, not 30 times like in my case.

These are my dependencies and I'm guessing one of this package versions throws this error without other details:

[image]

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.4.3",
    "@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.8.1",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.2.2",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^11.15.39",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.31",
    "async": "^2.6.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.5.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^4.0.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "csso-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "expose-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.1",
    "jest-date-mock": "^1.0.8",
    "jest-expect-message": "^1.0.2",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery-mockjax": "^2.5.0",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
    "node-notifier": "^5.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "ol": "6.5.0",
    "ora": "^3.3.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.20",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "semver": "^6.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "uglify-js": "3.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "^6.0.3",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.1.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-styleguidist": "^4.56.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.1",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.20.0",
    "webpack": "^5.62.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0"   },
```

Comment: This error comes from the `css-loader` package. Here is an issue about this exact problem on the github repo: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/873.

Comment: I removed `css-loader` package alltogheter, but it didn't fix it. I needed to downgrade `webpack-cli` from v5 to v4 and it removed the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems my issue was related to the `cli` itself. I needed to downgrade the `webpack-cli` package from `v5` to `v4` and it removed the error. Unfortunate fix though.